# I am getting error illigalargument exception while sending image uri to another screen composable using navigation

Tags: android, navigation, imageuri

when fetching image from external storage and showing in home screen then sending that imageUri to show in another image detail screen, but the app crashes when I click on button to show the image on detail screen,

This error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 15200
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that
> matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{
> uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/imageDetail/content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000028317
> } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0)
> startDestination={Destination(0x78d845ec) route=home}
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1787)

Comment: Can you share your code?